# Unable to create a table type on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have created a type defined as following:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TypeListingDatePrice] AS TABLE(
    [RowID] [int] NULL,
    [ListPrice] [int] NULL,
    [SoldPrice] [int] NULL,
    [PendStatusDOM] [int] NULL,
    [ListingDate] [int] NULL,
    [StatusDate] [int] NULL,
    [PendDate] [int] NULL,
    [SaleDate] [int] NULL
)
```

This works fine on SQL Server 2012, but I unable to do the same on SQL Server 2005. It gives an error on execution:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Your 1st source of info should be [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007(v=sql.90).aspx). Notice that in 2005 there is no `AS TABLE`. Also, are you really doing new development on SQL 2005? You know it's just barely on life support, right? [This post is almost a year old](http://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/13/are-you-still-running-sql-server-2005-now-is-the-time-to-upgrade-to-a-modern-data-platform/) - support ends April 12th ([more details here](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2910315/database/sql-server-2005s-end-of-life-clock-is-ticking-down.html)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to create a [user-defined table type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.100).aspx) was first [introduced in SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(SQL.100).aspx) and so it is not possible to do this in 2005.

See the answer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606263/how-to-create-a-table-type-in-sql-server-2005